# Should I update my java file to be entitled kotlin when translating to Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, naming-conventions

I've recently translated all Java files in my Android Studio app to Kotlin. However, I still have the java folder holding all of my Kotlin classes. Does this naming convention matter much? Is it possible to change it for posterity? Would this cause any issues? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't cause any harm. It'll just be confusing for any developers.

You'll notice that some projects have a `java` and a `kotlin` folder.

You can do this too, just remember that if you make a new folder, you need to mark it as a `sources` folder for your IDE :)

Comment: Like you said, most people probably don't eveb care. Your IDE already presents the folder in a good way so you don't have to think about it. Actually at least 50% of kotlin Android projects i checked out had all the kotlin code in a java folder.

Comment: You would also have to edit the config for Maven or Gradle to add a new source set (if applicable)

Comment: Thank you all! I'll go that route, with editing configs and all of that. I want it to reflect a modern-built application in every way; rather than one that was created and then translated.

Comment: It is now a convention, Mr. Hiddleston. We have experienced a paradigm shift in our lives, translating through Java to Kotlin, from the View System to Jetpack Compose, and this has made some nostalgic conventions become foundational. Like the source files being in the `java` folder, and the resources in `res`,  among others...